# Is there a way to shorten multiple .next()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you have

```
$('#element').next().next().next().next().next().doSomething();
$('#element').next().next().next().next().doSomething();
$('#element').next().next().next().doSomething();
```

Essentially, doing something different to sibling elements.

Is there a way to turn loads of `next()` into a specific one? For instance I wish I could do next(5) = next() five times.

1. Is there a way to do this?
2. Is there a way to do this for `prev()` as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

`.nextAll(':eq(4)')`

and for previous you can use [.prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/)

```
.prevAll(':eq(4)');
```

Comment: Is there a way to string them together in one selection? So if you want to target nextAll eq 1,2,4? I tried .nextAll(':eq(1)', ':eq(2)', ':eq(4)') but doesn't work!

Comment: then you can use :lt so .nextAll(':lt(4)') @user2413333

Answer (score 3):

Yes!

```
.nextUntil()
```

See this for all the details: http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

EDIT: Another answerer said .nextAll(':eq(4)')

This is true except - what if you don't know how many elements?  Well, you can find out of course but .nextUntil will work with a fluid and changing list of siblings until it meets a certain selector.

Comment: Hmm.. but in the OP - it's only selecting a certain one(ie.  5th sibling after the current one).  `nextUntil()` will all the following siblings until it meets a certain selector (1st,2nd,3rd,etc..)

Comment: Yeah.  .nextAll() and .nextUntil() are both good tools.  Depending on how literal/real life the problem that initiated the question above is, one may or may not make more sense than the other.

Comment: Indeed they are static siblings, so NextAll is perfect, however, I did not know about nextUntil either, and I know I will use it in the future, so thank you!

Comment: Just for more edumacation - there are all sorts of awesome traversing examples here (including parentsuntil, childrenuntil, etc etc): 

http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/